# Why is NRVO not performed here (mutiple returns)?

Tags: c++, copy-elision, nrvo

NRVO is not performed for `MyString ret` in the following method. The default constructed MyString (`return {};`) gets directly constructed into the target, ret is move constructed into the target.

```
MyString MyString::Substring(size_type idx, size_type length)
{
    size_type thisSize{ getSize() };
    if (thisSize - idx < length)
    {
        return {};
    }
    
    MyString ret{ length + 1 };
    for (size_type otherIdx{ 0 }; otherIdx < length; ++otherIdx)
    {
        ret[otherIdx] = (*this)[idx + otherIdx];
    }
    ret[length] = '\0';
    return ret;
}
```

If `MyString ret{length + 1};` was above the if-statement with the `return{};` in its body, it'd be clear to me why it can't be constructed directly into the target: If it were, and after that, the default constructed MyString object got returned, destruction of `ret` would be required, and the default constructed object would take its place. That is not desirable. But what is the underlying reason that, in this case, `MyString ret` can't be directly constructed into the target? When constructed in the code, it is well known that the function is not going to `return {};`.

I'm sure that I'm overlooking something here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here's a minimal reproducible example as @rustyx suggested:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = default;

    Foo(Foo&&) { std::cout << "Moved" << std::endl; }
};

Foo func(int i)
{
    if (i < 0)
    {
        return {};
    }
    Foo bar;
    return bar;
}
int main()
{
    Foo test{ func(-1) };
    Foo test1{ func(1) };
}
```

This prints:

```
(Nothing)
Moved
```

Comment: *When constructed in the code, it is well known that the function is not going to return {};* That information is only available at run-time. Optimizations are done at compile-time.

Comment: What compiler/version?

Comment: @rustyx MSVC with ISO C++17

Comment: @super This is how I understand it: The caller reserves some memory where the callee shall construct the return value. To enable RVO/NRVO, this memory is the memory of the target. Now when the function is called, this block of memory is still "empty". When the function has passed the if-statement, it is known that the only possible return value is ret, so it could be constructed there?

Comment: Yes, it could (for example GCC does), but unlike RVO, NRVO is not guaranteed, and it can very well be that MSVC can't do it. If you provide a [mcve], maybe someone can check the generated assembly to confirm.

Comment: @rustyx [GCC doesn't do NRVO in the reduced example](https://godbolt.org/z/ea11G56W7), so... But there's no reason it couldn't; I think all the compilers are just being stupid. Forcing it by wrapping everything between and including the construction and return in `return [&]() { /* ... */ }();`, should work.

Comment: Thank you all so much for replying to my question! :) So it actually COULD do NRVO, as I said. I thought I was missing something in my train of thought (I'm relatively new to C++ and programming in general.)